# How to create a python dict with a default value from a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of names (say months) in a list. How can I create a dict with same value (say 0) **without a comprehension** if it is possible in some way?

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
```

What need is:

```
months_values = {'Jan': 0, 'Feb': 0, 'Mar': 0, 'Apr': 0, 'May': 0, 'Jun': 0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
months_dict = dict.fromkeys(months,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
dict1=dict.fromkeys(months,0)
print(dict1)
```